# Composer autoload classes not working

Tags: php

I have this kind of project structure.

```
    ├───app
    │   ├───config
    │   ├───controllers
    │   ├───libraries
    |   |       Controller.php
    │   │       Core.php
    │   │       DB.php
    │   ├───models
    │   └───views
    └───vendor
        └───composer
         autoload.php
```

I want to load classes from libraries folder.

I have a file named `bootstrap.php` which is including `autoload.php` file and use of namespace

bootstrap.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'; 

use Libs\DB;
use Libs\Core;
use Libs\Controller;
```

in the `index.php` file, i'm not getting any output from any class. Class names are the same as the file name and have the constructor

example DB.php

```
namespace Libs;

class DB {

    public function __construct() {
        die("Hello");
    }
}
$db = new DB();
```

This is how composer.json looks like

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Libs\\" : "app/libraries/"
        }

    }
}
```

and lastly my index.php file

```
require_once '../app/bootstrap.php';
```

I cannot figure out why it is not working, can you please help me, what I've been doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run `php composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Is this **all** of your `index.php`? If so, you're not creating any instances of the classes you defined. In your `index.php` try something like `$db = new \Libs\DB;` (same as what you did in DB.php, but in index.php)

Comment: yes i used dump-autoload -o

Comment: @Nima Hi, thanks for an answer, first placc DB is printing out but when i try to output messages from two classes, only first one class is printing message and second doesnt, and if i comments first class then second is working. This is how id did `$db = new \Libs\DB;
$core = new \Libs\Core;`

Comment: That is because you're not `print`ing output, but you're calling `die` in DB class constructor, which terminates your application and prevents any further output.

Comment: oh sorry my fault. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're not creating any objects of the classes you defined, so the mechanism that includes class definition file is not triggered. I guess you expected the `use` statements trigger this mechanism to include those files, but this is not how it works. If you try to create an object of those classes, you'll see the constructor being called. So in your `index.php` add this:

```
$db = new \Libs\DB;
$core  = new \Libs\Core;
$controller = new \Libs\Controller;
```

to see the objects are being created correctly.